# large dataset problem

Tags: orange

my name is Lucas and I'm working with single cell analysis on my PhD. A few weeks ago I started using scOrange for my analysis, but I noticed that when I try to load large datasets (more than 60k cells), the load data widget does not load the dataset, with no error mensage at all. Is scOrange limited to a certain amount of data? Or is something else missing in the workflow?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. This looks like a memory issue. If you can, try to load your data on a machine with more RAM. Otherwise I would suggest asking on the [github issues](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-single-cell/issues).